# PassID # vs. Global Entry #

Tags: global-entry

I understand the difference between the PASSID number and the Global Entry number, what I'm not sure about is which one I'm supposed to give the airline for international travel?

Do they only need the PASSID number or do I need to give them the Global ID number instead?

Comment: What is the airline asking for? In booking tickets, I've seen airlines ask for passport numbers and Known Traveler Numbers. What has been asked of you?

Comment: They've asked for the redress number? But they've asked for the 9 digit number from the back, but they don't seem to know which one they want. I thought the PASSID would give them the access to the global ID number, assuming the numbers are linked.